# How to wait for the object to construct in async JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am starting with asynchronous JS and reached a problem which I couldn't solve. I am working with puppeteer to work with headless chrome. I got to work with an object which I create like this:

```
const dataLayerPuppeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId)
```

After that I am working with the object with methods which return Promise, so I could use await on them. However the problem is that I need to wait for the object to be created until I work with it because I am getting "dataLayer" is not defined error.

**My question is**: How to wait for the execution of this line of code and then continue with the rest of code with dataLayerPuppeteer already defined?

Thanks

**EDIT (full code):**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const dataLayer = require('puppeteer-datalayer');

(async () => {

    // Automate here
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const containerId = "GTM-5LDMPBF";


    const dataLayerPuppeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId);
    await page.goto('https://www.ifortuna.sk');

    await page.click('#header > nav > div.main-navigation > a'),

    console.log(await dataLayerPuppeteer.history());

    // console.log(await dataLayerPuppeteer.history());

    const div = await page.evaluate(() => {return (document.querySelector('p').innerHTML) });

    console.log(div);

    //await page.click('#header > nav > div.main-navigation > a');

    await browser.close(); 
})();
```

Comment: How is `dataLayer` being defined exactly?

Comment: It doesn't matter I just want to wait on this line of code to happen and then continue with my code... @deceze

Comment: No, it tells you that it has no idea what `dataLayer` *is*. It very much matters how and where it's defined.

Comment: It is a class in a module I am importing. @deceze https://github.com/justusbluemer/puppeteer-datalayer/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Show how you're importing it exactly…

Comment: I have added the full code there, thanks @deceze

Comment: Well, that should work as far as anyone can see. However, ***`dataLayerPuppeteer`*** isn't being defined anywhere [where it would make sense]. Is your actual error message that `dataLayerPuppeteer` isn't defined?!

Comment: well actually I just tried to run it and it is just stuck now without any error, it does nothing and I have to kill it @deceze

Answer (score 0):

That code does not raise *that* error. If anything it will complain about `dataLayerPuppeteer` being undefined in this line:

```
console.log(await dataLayerPuppeteer.history());
```

That's because you construct it inside a function scope with `const`, so that variable isn't valid anywhere but within the Promise callback.

A constructor cannot be asynchronous, the line `const dataLayerPuppeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId)` will always execute immediately, synchronously. There's no need to wrap it in a promise or await it in any way. So:

```
const dataLayerPuppeteer = new dataLayer(page, containerId);
...
console.log(await dataLayerPuppeteer.history());
```

This will do just fine. If you still have other problems elsewhere, that's a separate topic.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, however I edited the code once more, this is the current state and I get this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: dataLayer is not defined

Comment: ‍♂️ Can't reproduce that…

Comment: I can't find the bug :/ @deceze

Comment: Reduce it to the most minimal example. `console.log(dataLayer)` every step of the way.

Comment: If I console.log(dataLayer) after the goto method, i get: [Function: dataLayer] @deceze